Is there a way to disable VS Code "history" when searching?
When I use Visual Studio code to perform a search in a folder, it reopens files that I opened last time I searched that folder.
I was expecting no files to be opened and to just receive a list of files, so the open file list stays manageable. The search.quickOpen.includeHistory setting does not seem to work. Preferably my already open files not from the searched folder also shouldn't be discarded.
This is NOT about VSCode reopening previous files when simply opening the application, but specifically files opened, sometimes ages ago, when using the search option on folders.
